# How To set Plotarea of Core Plot Graph with Custom View

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I am plotting graph using core plot. I am trying to plot my graph on plot area, but it contains white background. But i want to plot graph with my own background. This is my code.

```
CGRect frame = [self.hostingView bounds];
self.graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

// Add some padding to the graph, with more at the bottom for axis labels.
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10.0f;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 10.0f;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 25.0f;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 30.0f;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill=[(CPTFill *)[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:    [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0]];

// Tie the graph we've created with the hosting view.
self.hostingView.hostedGraph = self.graph;
}
```

In above code i tried to change color but i want to draw horizontal dotted lines for each  ticks on y axis.

Answer (score 0):

To draw horizontal lines, set the `majorGridLineStyle` and/or `minorGridLineStyle` for the y-axis to draw lines from the major ticks and minor ticks, respectively. Use the `dashPattern` and `patternPhase` properties of the line style to control the dotting pattern. See Apple's [Quartz 2D docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html) for details on how to use those line style properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 //configure plot method 
    //0 - Create Theme
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];

    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.GraphView.frame];
    graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];
    graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
```